# In Polymorphism only derived class can be the base class, what happens here?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism

In Polymorphism I learned that only derived class can be the base class, but look at my example, a base class is now a derived class:

```
static void Main()
{
   Person a = new Customer();

   //here a base class is a derived class
   Customer c = (Customer)a;
}

class Person
{
}

class Customer : Person
{
}
```

Why this is possible?

**The members of the derived class should not be discarded when instantiated on a base class?**

**If I instantiate a derived class in a base class, the allocated memory size is the size of the derived class?**

Comment: Just say to yourself: "Client *IS A* Person" and it should all become clear: if Client is a Person, you can assign it to a Person object. If you know that this specific Person IS A Client, you can cast it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a is actually a Client object this would work fine. Let me be more specific:
a is a "variable" of type Person, it can hold an "object" of any type from Person to any of its child classes.
c is a "variable" of type Client and can hold an "object" of any type from Client to any of its child classes.

What you've done is put an "object" of Client into "variable" of Person. Wherever you move this object, it'll always be a Client object. So, what we need to keep in mind is that even though you put an "object" of Client into a "variable" of Person type, the object type is still client. In the next statement you just moved the object into its correct type.

A variable is just like a basket. It can hold anything which is smaller than it. If you take out the object out of the basket and put it into another basket, the object still remains the same.

Comment: The members of the derived class should not be discarded when instantiated on a base class? If I instantiate a derived class in a base class, the allocated memory size is the size of the derived class?

Comment: That's the whole point of polymorphism: BMW and Volkswagen are both Cars. Car A = new BMW(), Car B = new Volkswagen(); - anything that can handle a Car can handle a BMW, a Volkswagen or a Ferrari. It does not need to care. In .NET the specialties (variables) of the Volkswagen or BMW are both in the Car, but you can access them only if you cast the Car back to a BMW/Volkswagen. They are not lost.

Comment: You did not instantiate the derived class in a base class. You instantiated a derived class and put the address of this object in the base class variable. The memory size etc. doesn't get affected at all.

Comment: @SidharthPanwar Can you elaborate a answer about memory size in my example?

Comment: @Krumelur and about memory size allocated?

Comment: You create an instance of Client, hence the memory used will be that one required by a Client. Then you take a Person variable and let it point to your Client object. This does not change the amount of memory used by the Client.

Comment: When you say Person a = new Client(); two things happen - first a Client() object is created. At this point in time the compiler is not concerned where this object will be put. It just creates a client object. In the second step the compiler sees that the a variable needs to be created. It creates this variable and puts the "address" of the newly created Client object into the variable (before putting the address it checks whether Client is a subclass of Person or not, if not then it gives an exception). So you see there's no memory constraint in this case.

Answer (score 0):

While the above does work (as noted in other answers), the following would fail, which is probably the point of not trying to cast a base class to a derived class (unless you really know the type at runtime).

```
static void Main() 
{ 
   Person a = new Customer(); 

   //This will fail at runtime.
   Programmer c = (Programmer)a; 
} 

class Person 
{ 
} 

class Customer : Person 
{ 
} 

class Programmer: Person 
{ 
}
```